# How to share a .git folder among several projects?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-submodules, mercurial-subrepos

I want to work with Git repositories or sub-repositories [like in Mercurial Share extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShareExtension).

So, here's what I have:

```
mkdir orig
cd orig
echo "osthuaosteh" > abc
git init --shared
git add abc
git commit -m 'init'
cd ..
mkdir another
```

How can I initialize a repo in `another` so that it shares the repository with `orig`?

I need this for a big library that I want to include as a sub-repository. The repo weighs hundreds of megs, so I want to reuse some of the folders.

Update: I want to be able to have different revisions in different working folders.

Comment: For clarification: The share extension shares a single repository between multiple working copies.

Comment: @Laurens Holst: This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would ask you is: do you really need to share the repository?

Like Mercurial, git creates hard-links between repositories when you make a local clone, resulting in only little extra disk space consumption. E.g.:

```
git clone http://example.org/repo repo
git clone repo repo-copy1
git clone repo repo-copy2
```

Most files in the `repo-copy1` and `repo-copy2` repositories will hard-link to `repo`, and will not consume extra disk space. Only the files in the working copy are actual copies.

You can confirm this behaviour like this:

```
$ df -l
Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   976101344 217966872 757622472    23%    /
$ git clone --no-checkout repo repo-copy
Cloning into repo-copy...
done.
$ du -cs repo-copy/.git
63528   .
63528   total
$ df -l
Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   976101344 217967536 757621808    23%    /
```

As you can see, after cloning a 65880-block repository (of 512 bytes each), the block count on the file system went down by only 664 blocks.

If you clone a (sub)repository from a remote server you may have to manually create the hard links to other local clones; for Mercurial you would use the `relink` extension for that; the git equivalent also seems to be [called that](http://man.he.net/man1/git-relink).

Comment: Great! Will check out `relink` too.

Comment: This isn't the same as `share` as the clone is now an independent repository. I doubt that disk space is the issue here, more that the OP wants the two working copies to share a repository.

Comment: @PaulS: the question says that it is because the subrepo is so large. Culebrón’s ‘this is exactly what I need’ comment is probably in response to a comment I made and then deleted to flesh it out into this answer.

Answer (score 1):

With git-submodules that would be (and with your example) in path `another`:

```
git init # (to make another a git-repo)
git submodule add ../orig orig # to make orig a submodule of another
git commit # to commit the addition of the submodule
```

. Have you tried `git submodule --help`?

Comment: I read it and can't understand: will the (portions of) .git folder in `another/orig` be shared or not? I just want to save space and pull traffic.

Comment: `git submodule add ../orig orig` => `remote (origin) does not have a url defined in .git/config`. I do `git status`, says "nothing to commit".

Comment: Submodules are not the same (they are called subrepositories in hg). The share extension shares a single repository between multiple working copies.